# How to make a URL "un-secure" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to get the opposite of this:

```
Route::filter('force.ssl', function()
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
});
```

I have this:

```
Route::filter('no.ssl', function()
{
    if( Request::secure())
    {
        // return ???
    }
});
```

How do you make a URL not secure in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Redirect` facade has a `to` method that accepts a secure flag as its optional fourth argument. Therefore this should do what you need:

```
return Redirect::to(Request::path(), null, null, false);
```

Comment: Doesnt work hey. Get error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag::__construct() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in

Comment: You did include the `null` as the second argument?

Comment: I did. But I think you are looking at the wrong method. It should be : public function to($path, $status = 302, $headers = array(), $secure = null)

Comment: you were close... this works: return Redirect::to(Request::path(), 302, array(), false);

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the UrlGenerator class. I've edited my answer.